# Per-thread or per-task exception settings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio

I have a C# project. Is it possible to write code to the effect that "If an exception should occur while executing thus and such a task (and debugger is available), please break immediately, without unwinding the call stack."

Also, I just want to say, if this isn't possible, I'm fine with an answer to that effect.

Comment: I don't understand, can't you add a `try catch` block and add a breakpoint in the `catch` block?

Comment: the call stack gets unwound

Comment: There is not enough context in your question to understand exactly what you are trying to do and why you can't do it. If your code is throwing the exception, you can set a breakpoint at the `throw`. If some other code is throwing the exception, after you call it from your code, you can set the debugger settings to always break on that exception type instead of only when it's not handled. Please explain more precisely what it is you are trying to do and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception thrown in debug mode, but where?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15763898)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force break on any exception thrown in program](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1698154)

Comment: At the time I wrote this question, I didn't know where the exception was being thrown. It was one of those "once in a blue moon" exceptions, so setting a breakpoint for it was an annoying proposition. At any rate, I eventually got that answer. But more generally, I want to do exactly what I wrote. Seems like the answer to my question is "No, you can't do that."

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the System.Diagnostics.Debugger class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger(v=vs.110).aspx)

Using this class you can check to see if the debugger is attached and if it is you can break.

You could also wrap this in a static method on a utility class so you can use it easily

```
public static class DebuggerHelpers
{
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void BreakIfDebugging()
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
             System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
        }
    }
}
```

The Conditional attribute (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) will cause all calls to this method to be omitted when the DEBUG is not defined (AKA Release).

Comment: yes, but it's not per-thread, and I have to leave the point in the call stack where the exception was thrown.

Comment: Are you just wanting an easy way to ignore that a call to an external API throws an exception?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do it.  Your best bet would be some kind of IL weaver that would take your code and essentially wrap every statement in a try catch block and in the catch break if the debugger is attached to break.  This would keep your code clean and add the behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave the point where the exception was thrown and yet retain the call stack, you can do it only through logging the StackTrace AFAIK.

```
public static class Logger
{
  ...

  public static string CurrentStackDefaultLog()
  {
    // the true value is used to include source file info
    var l_CurrentStack = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true);
    return l_CurrentStack.ToString();
  }

  ...
}
```

A good link for implementing this code is given in https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223611/How-to-log-the-current-call-stack-in-NET by *Daniele Mazzeranghi*

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers, it seems the answer to my question is that it can't be done.